# How deadly would a singe mutant cockroach be in modern day Florida?

Tags: death, mutants, mass-death, insects

Ok, so this is a modified question from yesterday to hopefully meet WB.SE's rules about not being too plot- or opinion-based.

I had an idea about a freak incident in Florida where a cockroach sprayed with (probably Raid) insecticide inadvertently got into a microwave and was microwaved along with whatever the dude was cooking, resulting in a roughly man-sized killer cockroach, rather quickly, like in a minuet or so. What will I do with this info? No clue, probably make a Onionesque news report or a short story about it.

Regardless, here are the specifics:

1. The roach in question is either a German, American, or Smokeybrown cockroach.
2. This mutation gives the roach immunity to the negatives of Square-Cube Law (collapsing under its own weight, suffocating, etc.) and keeps its stats (mostly) the same, just at human scale (6 feet tall).
3. It is physically mostly the same, but as a mutant it is at around human-level IQ and can use its front and middle legs as arms and stand on its hind 2 legs like a human. It however, is strongly bloodlusted (probably from the whole incident) and will kill humans on sight regardless of age or sex. It is not afraid to try out ranged weapons, like guns or (thrown) stones, but much prefers melee kills with its bare tarsi or a club/bat/blunt weapon.
4. This takes places in modern day Florida, in a medium populated residential zone, so like a suburb or town, not a city or a highly rural area. The home it mutates in has a man, woman, and little boy and has no guns.  The time of day is around noon in spring-summer.

So how deadly would this roach be?

Now, this is a bit of a broad question, so let me give bullet points that narrow it down:

1. How high of a bodycount can it feasibly rack up before it is slain?
2. How hard would it be to bring it down, especially in terms of civilian weaponry?
3. How long is its reign of terror roughly?

I understand I can say it is any ol' number within reason, but I am genuinely curious about how this would likely pan out given the roach's racecar speed, pretty tough exoskeleton, strength, and ability to fly (depending on the roach type used as an example). I want some rough numbers I can work with so a prodding reader (and myself) can be happy.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145047/discussion-on-question-by-conan-highwoods-how-deadly-would-a-singe-mutant-cockro); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 4):

I stick by my previous answer:

Florida Man is packing, Florida Man shoots first and asks questions later, Florida man wants to have the bragging rights over a hunting trophy no one else has.

The Cockroach's life span is measured in the time between:

"Hold my Beer" and "Watch this"

And by Florida Man, I don't mean the family (as I know you've specifically said they aren't armed) - I'm talking the 1/3 Floridians that are Armed.

In terms of ballistics - this has come up before - the issue is that a Naturally occurring substances aren't generally very bulletproof. Yes, you can get glancing shots off the top of the skull (especially if it's from say a .22) - but most people aren't EDC with a .22.

Most people are using a 9mm or a .45 or something similar. That's just in the Handgun variety - when they pull out their long guns against the killer Cockroach - it's dead.

Crush injuries have a vastly different mechanism of injury to penetrating injuries.

In terms of rampage - even someone with a Human IQ **without Human life experiences** is going to get annihilated very quickly. Especially if the Cockroach kills the family and the kid.

Comment: Yeah, you have a point. I think 50 is pushing it, more like 10-20, maybe less if someone snipes it or something, even if it can live without its head, it is blinded. Plus, it is street dumb most likely. NOW...an iron clade beetle would pretty much have Superman level durability, so if it goes on a rampage provided it had guns and other weapons, I would say probably 100-1000 people get killed, maybe more assuming it knows how to operate a gun, given it can take getting ran over by a car and it takes drills to make a hole in it to pin it up.

Comment: But the downside(upside for Floridians) is that it probably is not that fast for its size, so most people can outrun it, plus I think it might be weaker proportionally than a roach, so it can be wrangled up or something and burned or whatever.

Answer (score 3):

## Magic?

You are asking us physical details about a cockroach that no longer follows the square cube law. But the square cube law is a property of physics and body engineering.

So to break the square cube law, the basic properties of your cockroach would need to change. They might need to not have an endoskeleton. Or perhaps they would need numerous small limbs to function, and the cockroach might need to look like an enormous millipede.

In any case, your cockroach would be radically different from a cockroach in the real world. You can provide it with almost any properties you like.

I would also add that microwaves are not in a wavelength likely to cause mutations. It can overheat cells and denature protein. But with all that material around the DNA, the cockroach would explode before it mutated from microwaves.

Comment: I understand that the circumstances behind the change and the fact that it does not obey the Square-Cube Law or maybe just found a way around it while still keeping the same form is not realistic, but it still can follow a bit of IRL logic in terms of its speed, strength, and durability. In this case, the scaled up speed of a cockroach. Contrary to popular belief, you can have a fantastical concept still follow a bit of IRL logic without just using taurscatium, not that there is anything wrong with that in general, just that it does not NEED to be the case 10/10 times.@

Comment: @ConanHighwoods the issue comes with what is probable versus what is fantastical. A real foot-long ant couldn’t pick up and throw a small car like it could if you simply scaled up a regular ant. A bullet isn’t simply a small artillery shell. The physics don’t scale the same.  Use common sense, but don’t try to make the logic any way quantitative.

Answer (score 1):

A giant cockroach would not be well equipped to deal with human prey; at best it might overwhelm someone who was incapacitated in some way. It would also immediately draw a massive amount of attention. As soon as anyone with firearms arrived on the scene the giant cockroach's ability to coordinate its actions would be shredded by gun shots. It might remain alive on its back wiggling its legs or running in circles for sometime, but lunch would not be on its mind after such an encounter. Any encounters with cars or trucks would also not end well for the cockroach.

Comment: Do you think they could tank shots from pistols and survive being run over? I heard they can take like 900 times their bodyweight before injury/death, but I do not know how true it is. Shotguns and snipers should work though, right?

Comment: The difficulty is in scaling. It depends how many liberties you want to take with the scaling factors (we've already hand waved away issues such as not having enough oxygen etc) 900 times a cockroach weight is not rely a large mass, 900 times a human weight is the weight of a very heavy tank and scales differently. I would have thought firearms would be deadly. If not immediately then they should at least disable and I would have thought being properly run over by a car would be very messy. I suppose they might take a shot or two if nothing vital was hit but emptying a magazine or a shot gun..

Comment: Hmm...I am thinking a speeding car might do it, and guns should work, I just think a revolver or something would be a bit weak against it. As for the scaling, all the stats of a cockroach scaled up to mansized(6 feet tall). @slarty

Comment: I think you could easily get away with "handgun resistant" for a story, as for scaling the problem is that volumes and areas don't scale the same so few grams of cockroach resisting a couple of Kg of force is a totally different question to an 80Kg man sized cockroach trying to resist a tank.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends where the cockroach goes. Cockroaches are remarkably sturdy ─ they can survive for weeks without their heads, and are almost impossible to kill by, for example, stomping on them. So your mutant cockroach might be very difficult to kill. If it can fly too, it might be very dangerous. Depends on how fast the military comes to investigate, but I'd put body count at maybe 10 in a rural area to 50+ in a city.